# Permutations associated to a transversal and Cayley theorem

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group with $H\le G$ and $T$ a right transversal of $H$ in $G$. $G$ acts on itself by left multiplication and so we can consider $G\le \mathfrak{S}_G$. Let $g\in G$. The permutation associated to left multiplication by $g$ is denoted $\sigma_g\in \mathfrak{S}_G$.

Now $G$ acts by right multiplication on $T$ according to $t.g=t'$ where $t'$ is the unique element of $T$ such that $Ht.g=Ht'$ (standard def for transfer map). This defines a permutation $\tau_g\in \mathfrak{S}_T$.

I am trying to see if there is any simple formula linking the two permutations. For instance, do these permutations have the same signature ?

Write $|H|=m,|T|=n$ so that $|G|=mn$. Let $M_g\in M_{nm}(\mathbb{C})$ be the permutation matrix associated to $\sigma_g$ and $T_g\in M_{n}(\mathbb{C})$ be the permutation matrix associated to $\tau_g$. Then $M_g$ is a matrix by blocks where for $1\le i\le n$ each block $B_i$ of size $m\times m$ is associated to the bijective map $.g: Ht_i\rightarrow H\tau_g(t_i)$. From that, I think I get 
$$
detM_g=\varepsilon(\tau_g)^m\prod\limits_{i=1}^n det B_i
$$
And easily $detB_i$ must be $\pm 1$. Now $det(M_g)=\varepsilon(\sigma_g)$ and so 
$$
\varepsilon(\sigma_g)=\varepsilon(\tau_g)^m\prod\limits_{i=1}^n det B_i
$$ 
Without further assumption on $G$ and $H$, I don't get anything better than this.

Comment: I doubt you can find a simple formula "linking" them even in the case when $H=1$, even though they are (non-canonically) conjugate in this case. Interesting question, though.